# Objective-C inheritance problem with UIView

Tags: iphone, inheritance, uiview, sdk

this is my inherited class of UIView : **MobileView**

```
@interface MobileView : UIView {
    IconView *icon1;
    IconView *userCar;
    id goTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IconView *icon1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IconView *userCar;

-(void) goRightInSeconds: (NSInteger)secs;
-(IconView *) cannon;

@end
```

I also have another class which inheritated UIView: **IconView**

```
@interface IconView : UIView {
    UIImage *iconImage;
    CGFloat originalX, originalY;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *iconImage;

-(id)initWithImage: (UIImage *)image andFrame:(CGRect) rect;

-(CGFloat) getX;

-(CGFloat) getY;

@end
```

Now, in another "main view" class which is also a subclass of UIVIew, I call this:

```
mobile = [[MobileView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 150)];
***[mobile cannon]***
```

Now i have an error: [UIView cannon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd1ae00'
(I still have the same error if I use [mobile icon1])

Why it doesn't regconize the mobile as a MobileView object but an UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    // ...
  }
  return self;
}
```

in your `UIView` subclass `@implementation`?

Comment: I used this:

self = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];

I guess that caused the problem.

YOU ARE THE MAN, ALEX.

Comment: @Alex

Is there a need to rewrite constructors for all subclasses?

Comment: I would override the initWithFrame and dealloc methods for subclassing UIView. Other subclass types may require other methods to be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call

```
mobile = [[MobileView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 150)];
```

How do you define mobile?  Not as a UIView *, I hope.

This is one way to do it:

```
MobileView *mobile = [[MobileView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 150, 150)];
```

Comment: no i defined mobile as a MobileView. 

The problem was in the init func that I used

self = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame]

but not this
(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])